# ASP.NET Core: Missed packages during Azure deploy from Bitbucket

Tags: azure, deployment, asp.net-core-2.0

We creating ASP.NET Core app and faced issue with deployment from Bitbucket.
Solution has 3 projects: Main project that runs application, DataBaseContext project and project that contains business logic. All projects using .net 4.7. Main project targets on netcoreapp2.0. 
When Azure tries do deploy code from Bitbucket it fails with following log:

[image]

Notice: all exceptions are related to DataBaseContext project...
What sdk\2.1.302 means? ASP.NET Core 2.1? But i have target on 2.0 in the solution.

Thanks. Any help appreciated

Comment: Make sure your DataBaseContext project could load Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore correctly and it has add the reference into the bin folder.

Comment: @JoeyCai locally it does. But on Azure does not. I temporary committed packges folder and it helped. But i need to find correct solution. 
Any way, thank you for the response!

Comment: You could try to add `<CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>true</CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>`to a `<PropertyGroup>` inside your .csproj file, which will enforce copying NuGet assemblies to the built output.